# Can a Jew work in non-kosher food warehouse?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, employment, non-kosher-species, hanaah-benefit

Can a Jew work in non-kosher food warehouse? I mean to lift boxes from one place to another, to load pallets filled with boxes of non-kosher stuff.

My question is about specific warehouse where there is no meat or milk, but where both kosher and non-kosher ready-to-eat seafood are packed, possibly in sauces with meat and/or milk ingredients.

And when lifting those boxes, it is clear what's inside them due to labeling.

Comment: AFAIK, the only problem with handling non-kosher items concerns meat / milk mixtures, which, from your description, doesn't seem to be a concern. I'm uncertain regarding 3rd party processing problems, i.e. if during manufacturing, the product was, say produced on a machine used for both milk & dairy. Of course, there may be other problems such as your being able to leave early for Shabbat, but I'm not sure if that's within the focus of your Q.

Comment: They don't store meat or milk there, BUT some products are shipped with sauce or mayonnaise dressings which MIGHT contain milk/animal source derivatives. Is that a problem? (and yeah, Friday and Shabbat are days off).

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5760/vayishlach.html

Comment: Not sure if this falls under s'chora